# Measuring distances between multiple polygons whilst avoiding buildings?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, shapefile

I am trying to map habitat corridors for different species of animals.

- A map with both habitat areas and buildings as shape files (shown in the image below)
- Maximum distance an animal will leave its habitat for
- Maximum distance an animal will travel

I want to map which habitat areas will link up.

I tried Cost Distance but I am not factoring terrain change in elevation so I don't think this will work.
I have also done euclidean distance with the habitat areas but I can't figure out how to get it to recognize buildings - at the moment it just goes through them.

[image]

Comment: Set buildings as barriers, i.e. assign very high cost to cells inderneath in your cost raster. Keep the rest small, e.g. 1

Answer (score 1):

I would copy/merge your buildings into one, multipart shapefile.

If you have spatial information to start with about where your animal roosts/nests/beds, then I would buffer off of those points to your specified maximum movement distance.

Finally, I would clip the buffer by the merged, multipart building shapefile. This should give you a polygon and will show you how the potential movement areas are connected.